# How to get headers from all responses using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, retrofit2

I'm using `Retrofit` library version 2 with `OkHttpClient`.

I want to get some header from all responses.

I found one solution with `OkClient`:

```
    public class InterceptingOkClient extends OkClient{
    public InterceptingOkClient()
    {
    }

    public InterceptingOkClient(OkHttpClient client)
    {
        super(client);
    }

    @Override
    public Response execute(Request request) throws IOException
    {
        Response response = super.execute(request);

        for (Header header : response.getHeaders())
        {
            // do something with header
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

But how i can do this if i'm using `OkHttpClient`?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is old question.. but still found to answer because myself too was searching similar one.

```
okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {  
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        // Request customization: add request headers
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "auth-value"); // <-- this is the important line, to add new header - replaces value with same header name.

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        Headers allHeaders = response.headers();
        String headerValue = allHeaders.get("headerName");
        return response;
    }
});
```

Hope, this helps!

P.S: no error handled.

Comment: please share me if u got any solution

Comment: @AnujZunjarrao my above answer is the solution. You can go ahead and use it, it will work.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.java) for that. Add it as an interceptor to your OkHttpClient builder while building the client, set the log level and voila! You will have all the information regarding the request as well as the response.

Here's how you can add the interceptor -

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
okHttpBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
client = okHttpBuilder.build();
```

There are four options when it comes to what you want to Log - `NONE`,`BASIC`,`HEADERS`, and `BODY`.

Now build the the retrofit instance with the above defined client and you will have all the data you need.

Comment: Question is to read all responses, something like a common super/base class, not activity level.